# add two parameters in Soulmate::Loader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

i have two fields in my model and i want add them in Soulmate::Loader:

for example, my "person" model has name and email field. and i want load then in Soulmate:

```
loader = Soulmate::Loader.new("people")
    loader.add("term" => name, "id" => self.id, "data" => {
        "link" => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.person_path(self)
    })
```

i want add `name` and `email` in loader.add. but i can't.

```
def load_into_soulmate
    loader = Soulmate::Loader.new("people")
    loader.add("term" =>{ name , email }, "id" => self.id, "data" => {
        "link" => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.person_path(self)
    })
end
```

and

```
def load_into_soulmate
    loader = Soulmate::Loader.new("people")
    loader.add("term" =>{ "name" => name ,"email" =>  email }, "id" => self.id, "data" => {
        "link" => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.person_path(self)
    })
end
```

error show when i use `Person.find_each(&:save)` for add datas to redis:

```
ArgumentError: ArgumentError
from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/soulmate-1.1.0/lib/soulmate/loader.rb:31:in `add'
```

but all is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use aliases.

```
def load_into_soulmate
    loader = Soulmate::Loader.new("people")
    loader.add("term" =>"name", "id" => self.id, "aliases" => [email], "data" => {
        "link" => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.person_path(self)
    })
end
```